# Como fazer matriz de correlações par-a-par incluindo interação com uma terceira variável?

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, gráfico, regressão, glm

Meu conjunto de dados segue essa estrutura:

```
Variável_1  Variável_2  Variável_3  Variável_4
3           5           0           6
5           5           1           7
6           7           3           5
9           6           3           10
12          10          5           10
```

Com os dados acima, criei uma matriz de correlações usando o pacote `corrplot` do R:

`corrplot (cor (dados))`

Digamos que, além das tradicionais correlações par-a-par, eu queira inserir uma terceira variável (`Variável_5`) em cada comparação, que interagisse com cada par de variáveis comparadas, seguindo esse raciocínio: `Variável Y ~ Variável X * Variável_5`. Há um modo de fazer isto no R?

Comment: Pode usar `lm`, extraindo o R^2 com `summary`. Confira a ajuda para `mapply` para aplicar `lm` para diferentes combinações de vetores.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta, publiquei essa mesma pergunta no Cross Validated, [aqui](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/600794/how-to-make-a-pairwise-correlation-matrix-including-interaction-with-a-third-var), e inclusive consegui chegar numa solução e deixei a resposta por lá. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado!